# how to use onChange attribute in dragger tag?

Tags: reactjs, file, antd, dragger

I implemented the file upload function using `<input type="file" .../>`.
But I wanted to try drag and drop function, so I imported ant design. 
In input tag, I used onChange to setState, but I don't know what to do with dragger tag.

Below is the source code using input tag.

```
  onFileChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            thumbnail: e.target.files[0]
        });
    }

.
.
.

  <Input type="file" namge="thumbnail" size="large" placeholder="Thumbnail" onChange={this.onFileChange}></Input>
```

and this is the ant desing's Dragger.

```
const { Dragger } = Upload;

const props = {
    name: 'file',
    multiple: true,
    action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
    onChange(info) {
      const { status } = info.file;
      if (status !== 'uploading') {
        console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
      }
      if (status === 'done') {
        message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
      } else if (status === 'error') {
        message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
      }
    },
  };

.
.
.
<Dragger {...props}>
   <p> ... </p>
</Dragger>
```

Is it okay to attach "onchange" to the dragger with props like this?

```
<Dragger {...props} onChange={this.onFileChange}>
   <p> ... </p>
</Dragger>
```

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is ok to use `onChange` on `Dragger` if you are already not using in its props. And in the given example there is already `onChange` property in `props` object that you are passing to `Dragger`, so you should not use another onChange attribute instead you can write your logic inside `onChange` property of `props` object

```
const { Dragger } = Upload;

const props = {
    name: 'file',
    multiple: true,
    action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
    //Here is onChange function written and you can use this to perform your action
    onChange(info) {
      const { status } = info.file;
      if (status !== 'uploading') {
        console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
      }
      if (status === 'done') {
        message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
      } else if (status === 'error') {
        message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
      }
    },
  };

.
.
.
<Dragger {...props}>
   <p> ... </p>
</Dragger>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add the file to the state from dragger then use this as an `onChange`.
Is it given in AntDesing documentation how to use `onChange` function for the `Dragger` you can use it but the `onChange` won't be giving you like `html` `onChage` gives, it will only give you one list of object, that contains:

first one is `file`

second one is `fileList`.

Here is the solution for your problem.

```
const { Dragger } = Upload;

const props = {
    name: 'file',
    multiple: true,
    action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
    onChange(info) {
      const {fileList, file} = info; // 'fileList' for multiple images and 'file' for perticular image
      this.setState({ thumbnail: file }); 
    },
  };

.
.
.
<Dragger {...props}>
   <p> ... </p>
</Dragger>
```